# refreshing datasource using Tableauserverclient python with source username and password

Tags: python, tableau-api

I am trying to use tableauserverclient library to refresh extract datasource in tableau server,
I managed to do it using the tableau desktop CLI, with this

```
./tableau refreshExtracts --server xxxxx --username xxxx --password xxxx --project xxxx --datasource xxxxx --source-username THIS_IS_IMPORTANT --source-password THIS_IS_IMPORTANT
```

without **--source-username --source-password** it's not working so what I am trying to do is doing the same with tableauserverclient library.

what I did is

```
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Update a connection on a datasource or workbook to embed credentials')
    parser.add_argument('--server', '-s', required=True, help='server address')
    parser.add_argument('--username', '-u', required=True, help='username to sign into server')
    parser.add_argument('--site', '-S', default=None)
    parser.add_argument('-p', default=None)

    parser.add_argument('--logging-level', '-l', choices=['debug', 'info', 'error'], default='error',
                        help='desired logging level (set to error by default)')

    parser.add_argument('resource_type', choices=['workbook', 'datasource'])
    parser.add_argument('resource_id')
    parser.add_argument('connection_id')
    parser.add_argument('datasource_username')
    parser.add_argument('datasource_password')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.p is None:
        password = getpass.getpass("Password: ")
    else:
        password = args.p

    # Set logging level based on user input, or error by default
    logging_level = getattr(logging, args.logging_level.upper())
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging_level)

    # SIGN IN
    tableau_auth = TSC.TableauAuth(args.username, args.password, args.site)
    server = TSC.Server(args.server, use_server_version=True)

    with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth):
        endpoint = server.datasources
        update_function = endpoint.update_connection
        resource = endpoint.get_by_id(args.resource_id)
        endpoint.populate_connections(resource)
        connections = list(filter(lambda x: x.id == args.connection_id, resource.connections))
        connection = connections[0]
        connection.username = args.datasource_username
        connection.password = args.datasource_password
        connection.embed_password = True
        print(update_function(resource, connection).content)

        resource = server.datasources.get_by_id('xxxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx')
        results = server.datasources.refresh(resource)
```

but still it does not take the embedded username and password I provided.

when I go to Jobs tab in the server I get **failed** Job status {Login failed for user 'private network user'. Integrated authentication failed}

any help ?

Comment: Can you confirm the TSC portion works with hard coded username and password rather than `args.datasource_username` and `args.datasource_password`?

Comment: @vizyourdata no it does not work